# Asp MVC PayPal Transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am trying to make a paypal handler. You type a money amount into an input, than you press donate button, you will be forwarded to the paypal page, you can login and than press continue button... The problem after I press the continue button its forward me back to the https://www.example.org/Account/PayPalHandler/ page, and thats it all. What is missing from my code to complete the paypal transaction?

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DoPaymentPaypall(UserModel User_)
        {
            ResultModel<ManageAccountListModel> res_ = new ResultModel<ManageAccountListModel>();
            res_.DataSelect = new ManageAccountListModel();

            if (SessionManagement.LoginnedUser != null)
            {
                var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
                var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
                var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
                string moneyCount_ = User_.moneycount.ToString();
                var payment = Payment.Create(apiContext, new Payment
                {
                    intent = "sale",
                    payer = new Payer
                    {
                        payment_method = "paypal"
                    },
                    transactions = new List<Transaction>
                                    {
                                        new Transaction
                                        {
                                            description = "Donation",
                                            invoice_number = "001",
                                            amount = new Amount
                                            {
                                                currency = "USD",
                                                total = moneyCount_,
                                                details = new Details
                                                {
                                                    tax = "0",
                                                    shipping = "0",
                                                    subtotal = moneyCount_
                                                }
                                            },
                                            item_list = new ItemList
                                            {
                                                items = new List<Item>
                                                {
                                                    new Item
                                                    {
                                                        name = "Donation",
                                                        currency = "USD",
                                                        price = moneyCount_,
                                                        quantity = "1",
                                                        sku = "Custom Package"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                    redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls
                    {
                        return_url = "https://www.example.org/Account/PayPalHandler/",
                        cancel_url = "https://www.example.org/"
                    }
                });

                res_.SuccessMessage = payment.links.ToList()[1].href;

            }
            res_.Success = true;
            return new JsonResult { Data = res_, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code above seems to only show the initial/start of the process...so *assuming* you mean *after* the user has approved your ***request** to use Paypal for payment* (don't confuse this as "the payment" - this step only indicates that the user as agreed to use Paypal for payment) you'll need to [`Execute` the payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/).

The link shows the full flow

- `Create` payment (this is what your code above maps to) - you'll get a `payment id` in this step
- redirect user to Paypal `approval_url` for approval (of the details in the `Create` above) using the `id` you recieved
- Paypal sends user back to your site with info on how to `Execute` payment (if user approves)
- `Execute` payment (this is done at  your site/app)

Hth

Comment: I already made it, I just read again the paypal documentation.. :) But thanks anyway!